# Azure Create VM with Skus=RS3-PRO using powershell returns error ErrorCode: VMAgentStatusCommunicationError

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-10

I have been using Powershell to create Winndows Virtual Machine and so far it has worked pretty well. 
My configuration looks like:

```
$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize Standard_DS2 | `
Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $Credential | `
Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsDesktop -Offer Windows-10 `
-Skus RS2-PRO -Version latest | Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id | `
Set-AzureRmVmBootDiagnostics -Disable
```

Now I have changed the -Skus value to RS3-PRO, I am experiencing long delay at step:

```
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroupName -Location $vmLocation -VM $vmConfig
```

It has returned error:

```
New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. ErrorCode: VMAgentStatusCommunicationError ErrorMessage: VM 'vmname' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.
```

> StartTime: 2017-11-15 20:59:34 EndTime: 2017-11-15 21:24:48
>   OperationID: d1dc18f6-2ac7-4205-b8e6-2fb74fa4cbf9 Status: Failed At
>   C:\pathtoscipt.ps1:144
>   char:1
>   + New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroupName -Location $vmLo ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand

The VM is created though and can be reached via RDP too. Sometimes, the operation succeeds too. 
I created VM with same image via Azure portal and it got created with no problem. I have following questions:

1. Does anyone have face similar scenario?
2. Where should I look for logs about what is happening when the VM is being created.

Comment: Can you find any error message in Azure portal?

Comment: I looked into "Activity Logs" and I can see that VM Creation is succeeded. If I look at status of VM in portal, it states "running" while the powershell prompt is still not returned. Even for a successful creation, it takes quite some time (aprox 20 mins) before it returns the prompt.

Comment: Yes, it seems powershell wait too long time, please try use this script to create another VM, when wait for the result, please try to type `enter` to refresh it.

Comment: Which version of your Azure PowerShell? `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`

Answer (score 0):

Your script works for me, I can use it to deploy windows 10 to Azure.

[image]

Could you please check your Azure portal to check if there any error logs about this deployment?

> Where should I look for logs about what is happening when the VM is
>   being created.

Maybe we can check Azure VM agent logs.

Here is the VM agent logs path:`C:\WindowsAzure\Logs`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely, I can see what agent was upto during this time. However I do not see any error here. I will give some tries to reproduce the problem. Typical thing, it failed whole day yesterday and now it is passing (taking more than half hour to create a VM but eventually passes)

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan-Ul-Haq ok, please try it, if you need more help, please let me know:)

Comment: Now I have a failure among several successful deployments. I can see the the end time in the failure message: **EndTime: 11/16/2017 11:07:41 AM** while looking into WaAppAgent logs file, the start line is: _[11/16/2017 11:09:28.07] [INFO]  WindowsAzureGuestAgent starting. Version 2.7.1198.802_ Somehow, Agent is starting after the process has returned an error. There is a vmExtension cmdlet after createVM, that actually gets executed successfully.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan-Ul-Haq  Could you please check your Azure PowerShell version with this command `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`, for now, the latest Azure powershell version is `5.0.1`, maybe we should upgrade it and test it again.

Comment: Mine is 4.3.1. I will try with 5.0.1 and updated the case here.

Comment: Hi, The problem is still there with azureRm Module updated to 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue - I managed to solve it by adding the `-ProvisionVMAgent` and `-EnableAutoUpdate` flags to `Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem`.

The issue may be caused by the VM Agent not being set up on the new VM, which prevented the VM from reporting back to the script that it had been created.